# javafx export PieChart to .pdf file without screenshot

Tags: javafx, charts

Is there any way to export javafx PieChart directly to .pdf without screenshot it as an image file?

Comment: Not a trivial one. You'd basically need to draw something that looks like a JavaFX pie chart in your pdf yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So far no way of doing it. The best way is to create the chart using Xchart library and export it as svg image or pdf using  VectorGraphics2D.